# Docker Container does not run on Azure Batch Service

Tags: azure, docker, azure-virtual-machine, azure-batch

I want to run docker containers on Azure Batch Service. I already used custom VMs and they are working fine. But using Container VMs I can see the completion of Job Successfully but docker container doesn't work as it takes only 7 sec for completion whereas if container would have run it would at least take 3-5 mins.

```
        CloudTask cloudTask1 = new CloudTask(
            id: "Task-1",
            commandline: $"/bin/bash -c 'echo RUNNING DOCKER'");

        cloudTask1.ContainerSettings =  new TaskContainerSettings(
            imageName: RegistryImages[0],
            containerRunOptions: $"--rm -v host:/host"
            );

        CreateUserPermission(cloudTask1);

        // Create a list of above tasks
        IEnumerable<CloudTask> cloudTasks = new List<CloudTask>() {
            cloudTask1
        };


        await batchClient.JobOperations.AddTaskAsync(
            jobId: jobId,
            tasksToAdd: cloudTasks
            );
```

I can see only the echo output in stdout.txt. Also, These containers depends on GPU so I am using GPU VMs. and I am using ubuntu-server-container-rdma (Azure VM Offer).

Comment: Which size do you choose for your backend pool? And do you take a look at the [Linux Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-pool-compute-intensive-sizes#linux-pools---virtual-machine-configuration)?

Comment: I choose Standard_NC6 for the pool.

Comment: What do you mean when you say using the Container VMs?

Comment: VMs configuration in Batch pool specific for running Containers e.g., ubuntu-server-container

Comment: The two images are all for the VM that supports the container. But if you do not need the RDMA, you can just use image ubuntu-server-container with size Standard_NC6. If the RDMA is necessary then you can try the image ubuntu-server-container-rdma with one of the sizes in the list H16r, H16mr, A8, A9
NC24r, NC24rs_v2, NC24rs_v3, ND24rs*. Different requirement with different image and size.

Comment: Do you solve the issue?